# Need to revert SPEntryPage changes in ServiceNow but can't access it

Tags: servicenow

I have a dev instance of ServiceNow and I was trying to figure out how to navigate an admin to a url and a regular user to a different url after successful login.

So in my experimenting and testing I changed this line in SPEntryPage

```
if (user.hasRoles() && !redirectURL && !isServicePortalURL)
     return;
```

And instead of just returning nothing I `return '/myPortal';`

But now I can't access ServiceNow... It always redirects me to my portal... Is there anyway I can get back to the ServiceNow admin dashboardy (not sure what its called) part to revert SPEntryPage script?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just go directly to your *Script Includes*

https://YOUR_INSTANCE.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fsys_script_include.do

Also you may try going directly to the **SPEntryPage** *Script Include*

https://YOUR_INSTANCE.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fsys_script_include.do%3Fsys_id%3D3647c37253221200b0b0547cedc587fd

If those don't work, you'll need to do a clone over your instance or put in a ticket with ServiceNow to see if they can resolve it.